# Adobe Illustrator changes the shape when saved as SVG

Tags: adobe-illustrator, svg, illustration

I finished making my bot illustration in Illustrator which currently looks like this
[image: Text]

but when i exported it as SVG it looks like this
[image: Text]

I tried altering many of the SVG preferences while exporting but none of them worked for me.
I did expands all the shapes before exporting but still the hands and the screen containing the eye gets all weird.

Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. Did you use any effects on any of the shapes?  If so, use Expand Appearance on them before exporting as SVG.

Comment: No i didn't use any effects. Made that with just the basic tools like curvature tool and rounded rectangle and changed their corner radius  @BillyKerr

Answer (score 1):

I think this issue has been resolved in newer versions of Illustrator, but this might help users of older versions (ie CC 2018).

Instead of exporting the artwork via the asset panel, or via the "export for screens" option, try:

file>export as>save as type>SVG

In the next dialog, type in 3 as the decimal input. The SVG file type is based on mathematical equations, so the decimal dictates how many decimal points the equation should calculate. That will give the mathematical equation greater accuracy, so you will have a more detailed file.

You can go higher than 3, but the added accuracy will start producing much heavier files, so 3 seems to be a good balance between detail and file size.

Expanding artwork and outlining fonts might help as well. If you have created rounded corners by dragging the corner nodes, you need to expand the object before exporting.

I hope that helps!

Comment: the problem is that the new shape tools didnt allways react to the dirty bit, when it was first introduced and exporter thought they were still ovals. But you could have just nudged a point with arrows and force it to reconsider object as splines. Anyway this affected all exporters.